# Google Vision Logo detection

Tags: google-vision

I would like to use the Google Vision Logo Detection API and I would like to know how many different brand logos can be recognized. I have just read "popular brands" .. Does anybody have more information on this?

Cheers,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on your dataset and how well you have labeled your dataset. In the Google Cloud Vision Object detection you can make your logo detector and from there each label should have at least 10 bounding boxes.